# How can I maximize a complex function of two variables?

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, maxima-minima

I was trying to solve a problem, and I was stuck in one part of my solution. Firs I should mention that I should have find a orthogonal projective operator $\mathrm{P} \in \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$ that maximizes this expression,
$\langle\Psi|\mathrm{P}| \Psi\rangle-\langle\Phi|\mathrm{P}| \Phi\rangle$, where $|\Psi\rangle,|\Phi\rangle \in \mathbb{C}^{2}$.
So I find the relative expression and it is:

$f(x,y)=ax+by+b^*\frac{1}{y}-b^*\frac{x^2}{y}+c$

which constants $a,b,c,$ and variable $y$ could be complex number and x is a real number. I thaught I can use $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0 and \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$ to find the maximum of the f, but I think it is wrong. How can I find the maximum value of the f?

Comment: The original expression $\langle \Psi \mid P \mid \Psi \rangle - \langle \Phi \mid P \mid \Phi \rangle$ is real.  You can maximize a real-valued function, but you can't maximize a complex-valued function because the complex numbers don't come with an order relation.  Your $f(x,y)$ doesn't appear to be real, so maybe something is wrong.

Comment: what does it mean to maximise a complex function?

Comment: I myself had a serious problem with that. Maybe I should assume that this expression should be real and then I solve it. Am I right?